# Pydot creates graph in one line

Tags: python, graphviz, pydot

I have used pydot to create a network link graph for my log files. However, my graph turns out to be a long graph. Any way to rearrange it? I have attached the image for reference

[Pydot graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFQCL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the bounding box for the graph using graph.set_size() this will cause graphviz to adjust the layout.

Comment: It doesnt work! The graph just got zoomed out and smaller ! Thanks for the attempt thought! Thanks :D